# InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index' when trying to get only selected item in a ListView

Tags: c#, .net, list, listview, streamreader

So I am trying to remove an item from a listview and a line from a text. I've used the SelectedItems[0] and it gives me an error. And yes I do have multiselect set to false.

error log:

```
 InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'.
```

my code:

```
        DialogResult msgBox = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to remove this port?", "Are you sure?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

        if (msgBox == DialogResult.No)
        {
            // Do nothing
        }
        if (msgBox == DialogResult.Yes) 
        {
            listView1.SelectedItems[0].Remove();

            StreamReader sr = File.OpenText("ports.cfg");
            string srStr = sr.ReadToEnd().ToString();
            sr.Close();

            List<String> linesList = File.ReadAllLines("ports.cfg").ToList();
            linesList.RemoveAt(listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index);
            File.WriteAllLines("ports.cfg", linesList);
            linesList.ToArray();
        }
```

Comment: When does that code run.  From the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.selecteditems.  If the window handle for the control is not created: _"The SelectedItems property will not contain any items"_

Comment: MultiSelect is a red herring; it matters not whether you have it true or false and whether you use SelectedItem or SelectedItems[0] - they all amount to the same thing. You could use SelectedItem for clarity, but it actually seems more logical to me that you should read your file into your listview, make changes, then write the file based on the list view, rather than reading the file again, and removing an item from the list read based on the index of the item removed from the list. At any point in time the listview represents the file the user wants, so write it to a file

Comment: @Caius: actually, [`ListView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview#properties) has no `SelectedItem` property. As for the rest, well...that's a matter of implementation preference, depending on (at least) whether the entire contents of the file do in fact wind up being stored in the `ListView`, something that often won't occur e.g. when there are fields in each record of the file that aren't relevant to the user display. There is also of course the question of how wise it is to use the UI object to store business logic data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Impossible to tell without a proper [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). But in the code above, you appear to first remove the desired item from the `ListView` itself, and then you attempt to retrieve the `Index` property from the same item, presumably the one you just removed.

`SelectedItems` will wind up empty as a result of removing the item (since you say you *"…have multiselect set to false"*), so when you try to retrieve the element at index `0`, of course there's not one there.

Even if there was, you would not wind up getting the item you actually wanted, because you've already removed from the `SelectedItems` collection the one you want to remove from `linesList` later. Any item still left in the `SelectedItems` collection would be a completely different item, and not the one you wanted to remove from the `ports.cfg` file.

Something like this would, I think, work better:

```cs
ListViewItem portItem = listView1.SelectedItems[0];
int portIndex = portItem.Index;

portItem.Remove();

StreamReader sr = File.OpenText("ports.cfg");
string srStr = sr.ReadToEnd().ToString();
sr.Close();

List<String> linesList = File.ReadAllLines("ports.cfg").ToList();
linesList.RemoveAt(portIndex);
File.WriteAllLines("ports.cfg", linesList);
linesList.ToArray();
```

The above, of course, assumes that by the time this code is reached, you've already confirmed that there is in fact an item selected. If that's not the case, then you also need to add a check for that, by inspecting the `SelectedItems.Count` property to make sure it's greater than 0.